# flash builder 4 - Reverse engineering tools (code to flow chart or UML diagrams)

Tags: plugins, eclipse-plugin, flash-builder, flashbuilder4

I was wondering if there are any tools (Free/Paid) available. Suggest me a good one or what you have used.

Suggest me if there is any plugin available for eclipse then I can try if it works for FB4 (if you are not sure if it works for FB4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one tool

This tool can be installed in all eclipse based IDEs

- I has created all class diagrams (models) of all mxml and as files
- Allows to create various UML diagrams (such as Activity, Sequence, class diagrams, Use case diagrams) by opening GUI withing the IDE and allows to drag& drop the UML models

So, I yet to find if it can draw any activity/sequence/flowchart diagram automatically (just for the sake of getting the big picture of the flow the project)

http://www.uml4as.com